# Check Google Map API key validity

Tags: google-maps, flash, disassembly, api-key

I inherited an old application, written in Flash, and which uses Google Map to localize some points.

The map is not working since some days ago, and I modified nothing on the server or the network configuration. The error shown is :

> Initialization failed: please check the API key, swf location, version
>   and network availability.

All i have is the SWF. I disassembled it to get all the information I can have, and I managed to get the Google API key. Now, I don't know from which account this key has been generated, if it is still valid and I guess I can't change the key in the existing SWF.

How can I check the key validity? Is there recent change about Google Map system which could have invalidated my key?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of September 3, 2014 Google has discontinued their Maps API support for Adobe Flash.  Please see the top of their documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/intro

It is recommended that you convert your application to Google Maps Javascript API v3.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right. Thanks for your answer @DanTheMan.